# How to cast unsigned long to time_t in 64-bits

Tags: c++, casting, 64-bit

I'm calling localtime in C++ like this in 32-bits with MSVC6 (Visual Studio 98):

```
localtime((time_t *)&FileData.LastAccessDateTime)
```

`FileData.LastAccessDateTime` is an unsigned long and this compiled and ran fine in 32-bits.  I'm now converting the code with VS2017.  It compiles fine in 64-bits but it crashes at runtime inside localtime b/c the upper dword passed into localtime is filled with garbage.  I know I can assign `FileData.LastAccessDateTime` to a temp time_t variable then take the address of that.  But I want to fix this without making a local temp variable because I have to fix this in 100 other places in the code.  I've tried to cast `FileData.LastAccessDateTime` to an __int64 but I get a compile error saying: '&' requires lvalue.  That seems odd to me b/c `FileData.LastAccessDateTime` has a physical address in memory, I'm just changing how to view it (or so I think).

So, how can I change this cast, on one line, to properly upcast an unsigned long to a time_t value?

Comment: 1. Does this need to be thread-safe (I'm assuming reentrancy is a non-issue for localtime)? 2. Is the use of a centrally declared function an option?

Comment: I suspect the amount of time it would take to properly fix this in the "hundreds" of places you state will be less than the time it will take to try and shim a an obtuse work-around. You could try and craft a `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` solution, but it's a terrible work-around imho.

Comment: How about fixing the code? I mean, put the localtime call into a separate function, put the conversion into this function, and call this function instead of localtime at that 100 places.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: yes, it needs to be thread-safe. So, no globals.  @Whoz: can't use `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` for this 64-bit code.  @geza: yeah a separate function, as you and Max mentioned, is probably the way to go.

Comment: @printffan: wise choice :) Don't cast variables like this, that code most likely has undefined behavior, if `time_t` is not `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the issue is that we need to provide a pointer to an 8 byte sized memory location to `localtime` while the one at `FileData.LastAccessDateTime` is only 4 bytes. So, we need to grab some space elsewhere.

**Option 1:** The 8 byte space will be on the **heap**. This should do it:

```
localtime(std::make_unique<time_t>(FileData.LastAccessDateTime).get());
```

The `unique_ptr` handles the heap allocation and cleanup. This of course costs you a memory allocation every single time. Whether that's ok is for you to decide.

**Option 2:** The 8 byte space will be on the **stack**. There is no way around a function-local object here, but you can wrap it into a convenience function (which you can hopefully have available in all those 100 places):

```
struct tm * localtime64comp(uint32_t* timer32)
{
  uint64_t timer64 = timer32;
  return localtime(timer64);
}

// ...

localtime64comp((time_t *)&FileData.LastAccessDateTime);
```

If you can't make this function available everywhere, this seems infeasible.

**Option 3:** Use a **global** (ugh) for space.

```
uint64_t LOCALTIME_COMP;

// ...

localtime(&(LOCALTIME_COMP = FileData.LastAccessDateTime));
```

This is obviously not thread-safe (edit: you could make it thread-local I guess) and still has the same issue of availability, so I would avoid it. But it would work.

Comment: thanks. Yeah, the separate function (option 2) is a good way to go.